# Why does every item in this array get overwritten with the value of the last item?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I am working on a C# Windows forms program, and I am doing an exercise in the basics of a genetic algorithm. What I am trying to do that isn't working as intended is as follows:

My code initializes two jagged arrays, and a normal array. The jagged arrays each have 20 items, and the normal array has 8. The normal array stores a genome for an individual, and the jagged `population` arrays store an array of these `individual` arrays.

When I call `generate_population()`, it's supposed to initialize each array within the jagged arrays with the correct length, then it populates said array with the return of `create_indiv()`, using for loops (the function returns an 8 item `individual` array), then it prints the arrays to a listbox by accessing the i index of the population array and printing that value.

This all works fine, it generates a set of unique `individual`s successfully and it prints those individuals by accessing and printing a specific index in the population array.

Problem is, if I run the `generate_population()` function once, then try to use the `population` array in another function, it shows that every single index value contains the same `individual` — the last one generated in the array.

Example:

Upon generation within `generate_population()`, `population[][]` shows itself as being populated by these arrays:

- 12345678
- 87654321
- 13579063

If I try to iterate through, and print all values of `population[][]` in another function, after I call `generate_population()`, I get this:

- 13579063
- 13579063
- 13579063

Does anyone spot the problem? This code does not represent the full program, only the parts I think I isolated the problem to. I am 90% sure that the problem occurs in `generate_population()`, but I could be wrong about that. 
I can post the full program if necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int[] individual = new int[8];
        int[][] population = new int[20][];
        int[][] workingpop = new int[20][];

        Random seed = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int[] create_indv()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                individual[i] = seed.Next(0, 10);
            }
            return individual;

        }

        public string genomestr(int[] indiv)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int value in indiv)
            {
                builder.Append(value);
            }
            string fin = builder.ToString();
            return fin;
        }

        public int[][] generate_population(int number)
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < number; i++)
            {
                population[i] = new int[8];
                workingpop[i] = new int[8];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                population[i] = create_indv();
                workingpop[i] = population[i];


                int l = i + 1;
                this.popchart.Items.Add("Creature #" + l + ": " + genomestr(population[i]));
            }
            return population;
        }

        private void pop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popchart.Items.Clear();
            generate_population(20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a variation on the usual "objects are references, using the same object in multiple places means that changes in the one object affects all places that one object is referenced". See the marked duplicate for one example of the many existing Stack Overflow questions that already address this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line inside method create_indv():

```
int[] individual = new int[8];
```

You overwrite "individual" all the time.

```
population[i]
```

point to the same "individual"